# RequestDate not update event I use RowUpdate event on SOLine

Tags: acumatica

I just created QT on 28-08-2016 and then change the businessDate to 30-08-2016 and copy it to SOOrder so after copy to SOOrder, I open the QT again and status will change to Completed. But RequestDate on SOLine didn't update.

```
protected void SOOrder_Status_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
  var row = (SOOrder)e.Row;
  SOOrderExt rowExt = PXCache<SOOrder>.GetExtension<SOOrderExt>(row);

  if(row != null)
  {
    if(row.OrderType == "QT" && row.Status == "C")
    {
      rowExt.UsrRequestDate = Base.Accessinfo.BusinessDate;
    }
    else
    {
      rowExt.UsrRequestDate = row.OrderDate;
    }
  }
}

protected void SOOrder_OrderDate_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
  var row = (SOOrder)e.Row;
  SOOrderExt rowExt = PXCache<SOOrder>.GetExtension<SOOrderExt>(row);
  if(row != null)
  {
    rowExt.UsrRequestDate = row.OrderDate;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in the wrong event. You have subscribed to **SOLine**_RowUpdated, which is event for details. But copy order function will update only document (SOOrder) and will not touch details. You should little bit rethink your flow.

But actually my questions is - why you do not what to use standard logic (as shown on image) that updates requested date for details?
[image]

Comment: As my requirement, I just want to check how many days from creating QT to QT completed. That's why I want to update RequestDate when I copy to SOOrder and I use this code on SOOrder, it works yet SOLine didn't.

Comment: If you want just to keep difference between order creation date and completion data, I suggest you just have a new custom field that you can update from business data when status is changed on SOORder_Status_FieldUpdate event
You always can recalculate time from Order.CreatedDateTime to your custom field

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void SOOrder_Status_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
  var row = (SOOrder)e.Row;
  SOOrderExt rowExt = PXCache<SOOrder>.GetExtension<SOOrderExt>(row);

  if(row != null)
  {
    if(row.OrderType == "QT" && row.Status == "C")
    {
      rowExt.UsrRequestDate = Base.Accessinfo.BusinessDate;
    }
    else
    {
      rowExt.UsrRequestDate = row.OrderDate;
    }
  }
}

protected void SOOrder_OrderDate_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
  var row = (SOOrder)e.Row;
  SOOrderExt rowExt = PXCache<SOOrder>.GetExtension<SOOrderExt>(row);
  if(row != null)
  {
    rowExt.UsrRequestDate = row.OrderDate;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think now you have duplicate logic in your code. Persist function will change RequestDate on *Every Save* with no mater what is the order status.
Your event will do the same but only for completed line.

I still think that you using wrong approach for your task - you need time difference between creating and completing order, just create a custom field and calculate it (based on whatever) when you set complete status for QT order.

Comment: @SergeyMar, it's okay, I got it. Thanks

Comment: @SergeyMar, I've already created new field and take condition as OrderType == 'QT' && Status == 'C' but why it still didn't update my new customized field?